# What is the purpose of apply scale option?

Tags: modeling, transforms, scale, units

I know why we have to apply scale but what purpose does it serve ? Why not keep object scale to always 1  ? 
Thank you.

Comment: in the linked page I think the Duarte's explanation is quite good, a bit short though, it might have needed some examples

Answer (score 0):

Scaling in object mode can be used for animation and other purposes. Sometimes you might change it by mistake instead of changing it in edit mode, so that's the purpose of applying scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine scaling an object in Blender like stretching / shrinking the original shape, or like adding some scale modifier to an object - you are modifying the final proportions, but the object keeps it's original shape internally.

The advantage is obvious - it let's you easily revert back to it's main shape by setting scale = 1.

After you hit *Apply*,  the scaling will transform into it's main shape (mesh), so the object is no longer scaled. Exactly the same way like applying any modifier.

*Applying scale / location / rotation is one of the Blender's features that can be little confusing in the very beginning, but will start to make sense for you once you get used to Blender's workflow.*

Comment: It is not at all Blender specific? Every 3D application uses this concept.

Comment: It is possible, but I have tried to explain it in a beginner-friendly form - I remember that this behavior was not clear for me as well in the very beginnings, even though I had some experiences with 3Ds Max.